# Please upgrade your Stripe CLI to the latest version to use this feature

Tags: visual-studio-code, stripe-payments

I am getting this error when I start up VS Code.

> Please upgrade your Stripe CLI to the latest version to use this feature.

How do I upgrade the Stripe CLI to the latest?

Comment: You can follow the installation steps [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-cli#install).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
brew upgrade stripe/stripe-cli/stripe
```